# While performing selection of column using plydata package in python is ther any way to select only numeric columns without selecting the boolean

Tags: python

Is there any way to select only the numeric column and not boolean column using plydata package.

```
titanic_data >> select('-alive') >> select_if('is_numeric') >> select_if('-is_bool')
```

also is there any way we can deselect few columns based on columns found in some other dataframe.

Comment: As you are using Pandas you could use `df2 = df.select_dtypes(exclude = 'bool')` or if required also **include** specific dtypes.  See [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html)

Comment: I tried it and it was working but I wanted to know how it is done using plydata package in python

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same, I used call function from plydata package

```
x1 = (titanic_df >> select_if('is_bool')).columns
titanic_df >> select_if('is_numeric') >> call(pd.DataFrame.drop, x1, axis = 1)
```